# Group policy -- Forcing two proxy servers to clients

Tags: group-policy

I want to push two different group policies with proxy server settings to two different sets of desktop clients on the same network. It's been a couple of years since I've done anything on group policy so am a bit worried about ticking the wrong box etc.

Whats is the best way to implement this.

Comment: What distinguishes the two sets of clients? Subnet? Site? Group Membership? OU? The User that logs on? More info needed to give a useful answer.

Comment: Nothing currently distinguishes the clients they are on a flat default group policy, what I have is the host names that require policy 1 and host names that need policy 2.

Comment: Is this a rigid structure or can it be changed? My immediate thought from the info is to group the computers into separate OUs, and link one policy to one OU and the other to the second OU. Other things you might want to consider is which browsers are available? ADM templates are available for the most common browsers, so what you are looking to achieve is possible.

Comment: Thanks it looks like its not possible to this on a computer based level only user, which is a major pain given the structure of my AD.

Comment: It is possible on a per computer basis, you can do this by setting the scope of the policy to specific computers. You'd be better off organising the systems into OUs, or even adding the computers to groups and setting to the scope to the specific OUs or groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

**Move the computers to individual OUs.**

Group computers together in separate OUs, and create two new policies and link one to each OU. (Note on the image, the area highlighted in red shows where each policy is linked). Then simply configure each policy as required.

**Add computers to a domain group**

If you have no flexibility (or control) of the structure of AD, create two groups, and add the computer objects to the groups. Create two policies, and in the security section, remove 'authenticated users' and add (green highlighted button) one group to each policy. Configure the policies accordingly.

**Add computer to security filtering**

Possible, but a last resort IMHO. Same as above, but no need to create a group. Simply remove 'authenticated users' from security filtering, and add the computer object individually via the green highlighted button.

Be aware, that any policy settings you make, should be under the Computer Configuration part of the policy. User configuration will not apply to computers, unless of course you enable [Loopback Group Policy Processing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287).

[image]